# Add default code in wordpress post

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, plugins

I want to add a simple code to all new post by default
I tried to used this code in .function.php (wpbeginner)

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
    function my_editor_content( $content ) {
        $content = "If you like this post, then please consider retweeting it or sharing it on Facebook.";
        return $content;
    }
```

I am using plugin named **Shortcodes Ultimate**
Code:

```
[su_spoiler title="Download The File" style="fancy" icon="chevron-circle"]Here[/su_spoiler]
```

I tried to normal use simple html and CSS code but it show the same error for both cases

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgAs4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -: wrap your code is a single quote as you are already using double quotes.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = '[su_spoiler title="Download The File" style="fancy" icon="chevron-circle"]Here[/su_spoiler]';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to append the content to the $content variable ie $content .= "blah blah"